# laravel 5 maintenance page broken during composer update

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

When I update my laravel 5 app with `php artisan down && composer update`, the maintenance page does not show up, but an error appears. (whoops, something went wrong...)

The log has this error:

```
production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'file_put_contents(/var/www/app/vendor/services.json): 
failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:74
```

After the update, the maintenance page works again. When I look into the `vendor` directory I see this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 hannes http    4096  4. Feb 17:40 psr
drwxr-xr-x  3 hannes http    4096 17. Mär 18:20 psy
drwxr-xr-x  9 hannes hannes  4096 22. Mär 10:42 sebastian
-rw-r--r--  1 hannes hannes 10297 22. Mär 10:44 services.json
drwxr-xr-x  3 hannes http    4096 14. Mär 17:32 swiftmailer
drwxr-xr-x 15 hannes http    4096 22. Mär 10:42 symfony
```

The `services.json` does not have `http` as `group`.

Here is the `scripts` part of my composer.json:

```
    "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
    }
```

What could I do to ensure that my maintenance page is always working during the composer update? I don't understand what is happening there.

Comment: You are doing that update IN PRODUCTION without prior testing?

Comment: at first locally (arch), and then on the vserver (ubuntu). I guess this is not good.. ..but don't know how to test better

Comment: For a start: Update locally, then commit the changed `composer.lock` to your repository, move the repository to production and there only run `composer install` to install exactly the version you tested locally with. Expect a downtime nonetheless because updating/installing with composer will delete parts that your maintenance page needs before installing the new parts and the autoloader that make it accessible.